# HttpClient - When to use HttpHost parameter when executing HttpRequest

Tags: httprequest, httpclient, apache-commons-httpclient, http-host

When using the following code:

```
URIBuilder uriBuilder = new URIBuilder(url);
HttpPost httpRequest= new HttpPost(uriBuilder.build());
HttpHost httpHost= new HttpHost(uriBuilder.getHost(), uriBuilder.getPort(), uriBuilder.getScheme());
```

When is it a good practice to use

```
httpClient.execute(httpHost, httpRequest);
```

Because httpHost's host can be determined by HttpRequest which includes the URL

```
/**
 * Executes HTTP request using the default context.
 *
 * @param target    the target host for the request.
 *                  Implementations may accept {@code null}
 *                  if they can still determine a route, for example
 *                  to a default target or by inspecting the request.
 * @param request   the request to execute
 *
 * @return  the response to the request. This is always a final response,
 *          never an intermediate response with an 1xx status code.
 *          Whether redirects or authentication challenges will be returned
 *          or handled automatically depends on the implementation and
 *          configuration of this client.
 * @throws IOException in case of a problem or the connection was aborted
 * @throws ClientProtocolException in case of an http protocol error
 */
HttpResponse execute(HttpHost target, HttpRequest request)
```

Is there any benefit over calling

```
httpClient.execute(httpRequest);
```

Is it proxy/firewall/balancer related solution? When host will be different than URL's host?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs,

> Implementations may accept null if they can still determine a route,
>   for example to a default target or ***by inspecting the request***.

Your question

> httpHost's host can be determined by HttpRequest which includes the
>   URL

just paraphrases what is written in the docs.

There is no benefit of calling one over the other in your case. But, for advanced configurations, you can refer [this](https://www.baeldung.com/httpclient-advanced-config) where explicitly you may need to use HTTPHost. Hope this helps!